# Problema con la api de mercadopago mastercard

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago

Tengo problemas a la hora de usar tarjetas de prueba de mastercard.
Con las otras no hay ningun problema, el paso se procesa y me dice que se realizo con exito...

Diganme si precisan parte del codigo y lo agrego

> Client error: `POST https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments?access_token=(aqui iria mi access token)` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"message":"Cannot infer Payment
> Method","error":"bad_request","status":400,"cause":[{"code":2131,"description":"payment
> (truncated...)

Comment: En Postman tienes el mismo error?

Comment: ¿Tuviste alguna solución? Estoy con el mismo inconveniente y no encuentro como resolverlo

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, sólo parecería funcionar con la tarjeta de prueba VISA 4509953566233704 | cvc 123 y con vencimiento 11/25 Alguno pasó su proyecto a producción y pudo probar con tarjetas reales?

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso el problema está en los números de tarjetas de test que proporciona MercadoPago el la documentación general. Lo pude resolver usando los números que MercadoPago da en esta página en particular:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/v1/testing/

Con estos números, el pago con VISA funciona bien (con Master, no)
Espero te sirva el dato.

Answer (score 1):

Después de varias pruebas con el mismo problema me encontré con que el SDK de front al colocar la tarjeta mastercard devuelve como paymentMethodId "mastercard". Y en el back (en mi caso es un node pero puede ser por lo mismo) recibe como válido el string "master" y "mastercard" lo rebota. Me suena extraño que una empresa grande como ML se coma algo como eso así que probé actualizar librerias en front y back y el problema persistió.

Por lo pronto enviar el string "master" cuando el paymentMethodId es "mastercard" me funciona. Espero sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Después de indagar unas cuantas horas me encontré con esto, espero les sea de utilidad a todos los futuros internautas.

Error 2131 Mercado Pago - cannot infer payment method

**Cannot infer Payment Method:**
Se quiere pagar con una tarjeta distinta al tipo de tarjeta seleccionado. Por ejemplo, se ingresó el número de una tarjeta de crédito en la opción de tarjeta de débito.

Fuente:

https://github.com/mercadopago/devsite-docs/blob/development/guides/plugins/unofficial/vtex.es.md#errores-comunes
(Se dirigen hasta el final de la página)