# Error API mercadopago: Cannot infer Payment Method

Tags: php, laravel, api, mercadopago

Estoy en sandbox y estoy teniendo un error en al enviar el formulario con los datos de la tarjeta usando las tarjetas de crédito de prueba que brinda la documentación
(https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/api/testing/)
[image: Error:]

Sin embargo, cuando utilizo la tarjeta VISA de una documentación antigua el formulario se envía correctamente y devuelve el pago como aprobado (https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/v1/testing/)

Comment: A simple vista, es el mismo problema que se planteo en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333996/problema-con-la-api-de-mercadopago-mastercard)

Comment: Si la vi, espero que solo sea un error de sandbox y no pase en producción con tarjetas reales, porque es un error raro y de cliente encima